# Create migrations with EF Core in Xamarin Android project

Tags: xamarin.android, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I tried to use EFCore with SQLite in a Xamarin.Android project. I also added the package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools. When I try to create database migrations I get various errors.

When running `dotnet ef migrations add migrationname` on the command line I get the error

> No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

When running `Add-Migration migrationname` in Package Manager Console I get error

> Startup project 'MyProject' targets framework 'MonoAndroid'. The Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools don't support this framework.

Is there some way around this? Do I have to use EF6 instead of

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [guidance for unsupported frameworks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/#frameworks) is to move your `DbContext` code into a .NET Standard class library and use a dummy .NET Core console app with the tools.

```
cd MyDbContextProject
dotnet ef migrations add MyMigration --startup-project ..\MyDummyProject
```

Comment: Ok. Found this after posting my question but wanted wanted so see if there are some better solutions.

Comment: You want feature [#7152](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7152).

Comment: extracting https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell
`The Package Manager Console tools work with .NET Core or .NET Framework projects. Apps that have the EF Core model in a .NET Standard class library might not have a .NET Core or .NET Framework project. For example, this is true of Xamarin and Universal Windows Platform apps. In such cases, you can create a .NET Core or .NET Framework console app project whose only purpose is to act as startup project for the tools. The project can be a dummy project with no real code — it is only needed to provide a target for the tooling.`